# javascript countdown in html code of homepage

Tags: javascript

I added a javascript in a contenteditor on my homepage, the javascript is a countdown to a specific date in days.

When I put it in my HTML it works well, but after a day the counter shows me first the number it was the day before (when I saved it) and then after a second appears the right number for today!

If I check the HTML: the code is changed by saving it the day before with the counter of yesterday

How can I solve this problem

This is the script I use :

```
<!-- BEGIN Webmaster Web javascript countdown script -->
<div id="wmweb_countdown_1457339341970"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// Copyright (C) 2010 Ryan Wittering @ Webmaster Web - www.wmweb.nl
// URL: http://www.wmweb.nl/generators/javascript_countdown
function do_wmweb_countdown_wmweb_countdown_1457339341970()
{
// begin variabelen -
var na_countdown = "De tijd gaat snel. Gebruik hem wel...";
var voorvoegsel = "Aftellen naar de JCI Audit";
var achtervoegsel = "";
var style = "font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 14px; color: #DC1D49;";
var toon_seconden = false;
var toon_minuten = false;
var toon_uren = false;
var toon_dagen = true;
var stamp_datum = 1465164000;
var divid = "wmweb_countdown_1457339341970";
// - einde variabelen
var stamp_nu=Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);var sum=Math.round(stamp_datum-stamp_nu);if(sum<=0){document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML="<span style=\""+style+"\">"+na_countdown+"</span>";}else{var te_tonen_dagen=0;if(toon_dagen==true){te_tonen_dagen=Math.floor(sum/86400);if(te_tonen_dagen>0){sum=Math.floor(sum%86400);}}var te_tonen_uren=0;if(toon_uren==true){te_tonen_uren=Math.floor(sum/3600);if(te_tonen_uren>0){sum=Math.floor(sum%3600);}}var te_tonen_minuten=0;if(toon_minuten==true){te_tonen_minuten=Math.floor(sum/60);if(te_tonen_minuten>0){sum=Math.floor(sum%60);}}var te_tonen_seconden=0;if(toon_seconden==true){te_tonen_seconden=sum;}var items=[];items[0]=[];items[0]['name']='dagen';items[0]['nameOne']='dag';items[0]['amount']=parseInt(te_tonen_dagen);items[1]=[];items[1]['name']='uren';items[1]['nameOne']='uur';items[1]['amount']=parseInt(te_tonen_uren);items[2]=[];items[2]['name']='minuten';items[2]['nameOne']='minuut';items[2]['amount']=parseInt(te_tonen_minuten);items[3]=[];items[3]['name']='seconden';items[3]['nameOne']='seconde';items[3]['amount']=parseInt(te_tonen_seconden);var showedItems=[];for(i in items){var item=items[i];if(item['amount']!=undefined&&item['amount']>0){showedItems.push(item);}}var result="";for(i in showedItems){var showedItem=showedItems[i];i=parseInt(i);if(showedItem.amount!=undefined){if(i+1==showedItems.length&&i>0){result+=' en ';}else if(i>0){result+=', ';}result+=showedItem['amount']+' '+(showedItem['amount']==1?showedItem['nameOne']:showedItem['name']);}}}document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML="<span style=\""+style+"\">"+voorvoegsel+" "+result+" "+achtervoegsel+"</span>";
}
setInterval("do_wmweb_countdown_wmweb_countdown_1457339341970();",1000);
</script>
<!-- EINDE Webmaster Web javascript countdown script -->
```

Comment: Could you please post your code so we can better troubleshoot.

Comment: Show us your code. sounds like the typical countdown which does not do an init but just an update every second (so it takes a second to update correctly)

Answer (score 1):

If your javascript updates the content inside the Content Editor Web Part while in EDIT MODE on the page, then that update will be saved when you save your page.  It sounds like you had the page open in EDIT MODE,  the javascript executed and updated the countdown content, and you clicked Save.  So now the default content in the Content Editor Web Part has the countdown content you saved and it's automatically updated when the javascript executes.

Try checking to see if the page is in design mode and only executing the countdown javascript if it isn't.

```
var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;
if (inDesignMode) {
    startCountdownScript();
}
```

Alternatively, fade the countdown in after 1 second.

```
setTimeout($("#countdown").fadeIn(), 1000);
```

Comment: Hello James, this is the script :

Comment: Hello James ,tried yr solutions, but it doesn't worked. Mabe i do st wrong ... thanks already . Tried to add the script but i think its too long.